# Why does my getComputedStyle console.logs initial values

Tags: javascript, html, css, getcomputedstyle

I wanted to use `getComputedStyle` to access css properties, unfortunately it only `console.log()`'s standard properties.

Below you will find my code.

On the picture you will find what it logs.

[image: logs]

```
<body>
    <div id="box">box</div>


    <script>
        const box = document.getElementById("box");
        
        const boxCS = window.getComputedStyle(box)
        
        console.log(boxCS.zIndex)
        </script>
</body>

<style>
    #box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Because you put your style tag after the script tag (in fact outside the body which isn't even valid).

Comment: Related: [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](/q/14028959/4642212). The current best practice is to include your JavaScript code as a [module](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) using `<script type="module">`…`</script>` which solves this problem and many more.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One of the reasons is that you declare styles after the `script`.
If you put it before `script`, it'll be okay.
[Example](https://playcode.io/1022340)

Comment: @idleberg's answer is better if you need to leave the DOM as is

Answer (score 2):

Your script is running before the rendering of the DOM is complete. Try wrapping your preset in an event-listener. That way it's irrelevant in which order scripts and styles are inlined or loaded externally.

**Example**

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const boxElement = document.getElementById("box");
    const boxStyle = window.getComputedStyle(boxElement)
        
    console.log(boxStyle.zIndex)
});
```

Refer to the [MDN documentation on DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event) for details.